# Comparing Age being populated using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium Webdriver for automation and need to retrieve the current age of a person to compare it with the age populated in the application.

My Code goes like :

```
String DOB = driver.findElement(By.id("")).getAttribute("value");
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy"); 
Date convertedDate = dateFormat.parse(DOB);

Calendar currentDate = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
Date currentNow = currentDate.getTime();

System.out.println("Sys date: " + currentNow);
System.out.println("DOB Date: " + convertedDate);
```

Output:

```
Sys date: Tue Mar 05 12:25:19 IST 2013
DOB Date: Wed Mar 15 00:00:00 IST 1967
```

How can I retrieve the proper age so that I can compare it with application's age being auto-populated. Currently when we subtract by using `.getYear()` it is assuming the date of the year starting from Jan 1, hence not calculating the proper age.

Please help me on this so that I can successfully calculate the correct age.

Comment: check if this link serves your purpose.
http://www.javahelpandsupport.in/2011/09/program-for-calculating-age-of-person.html

Answer (score 0):

If you're already comparing years, why not compare the Month/Day to the current one? The Calendar can do this for you with a little bit of coaxing.

```
    //Retrieve date from application
    String DOB = driver.findElement(By.id("")).getAttribute("value");

    //Define the date format & create a Calendar for this date
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("MM-dd-yyyy");
    Calendar birthday = Calendar.getInstance();
    birthday.setTime(sdf.parse(DOB)); 

    //Create a Calendar object with the current date
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();

    //Subtract the years to get a general age.
    int diffYears = now.get(Calendar.YEAR) - birthday.get(Calendar.YEAR);

    //Set the birthday for this year & compare
    birthday.set(Calendar.YEAR, now.get(Calendar.YEAR));
    if (birthday.after(now)){
        //If birthday hasn't passed yet this year, subtract a year
        diffYears--;
    }
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Please check whether this helps you. 
This method will give exact years in numbers.

```
public static int getDiffYears(Date first, Date last) {
    Calendar a = getCalendar(first);
    Calendar b = getCalendar(last);
    int diff = b.get(YEAR) - a.get(YEAR);
    if (a.get(MONTH) > b.get(MONTH) || 
        (a.get(MONTH) == b.get(MONTH) && a.get(DATE) > b.get(DATE))) {
        diff--;
    }
    return diff;
}
```